# Not able to use latest version of three js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am not able to use latest version of three.js(r102) in IE. Getting ImageBitMap error(ImageBitMap is not defined). Any help in resolving this will be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please upgrade to version `R103`. The previous version resized images in a wrong way causing various problems. The related PRs are:

https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/pull/15900

https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/pull/15904